# RDLC Report Designer Clear a Filter

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, filter, reportviewer, rdlc

RDLC Experts there ?? I need to clear filters with an expression

I don't want to filter if the Parameter is null or empty.. need to filter only when parameter contains a value. but i am unable to reach that similar to the code below. i used this expression in my filter. (if customer id equals to null don't filter else filter).

```html
=IIf(Fields!Customer_ID.Value = "","", Fields!Customer_ID.Value)
```

Comment: So you want to check if `Fields!Customer_ID.Value` is `null` or not ?

Comment: checking for **null** is okey.. i need it **not to filter** if it is null.. it gives a 0 rows if i run this code..means gives empty rows. thanks

Comment: For checking the `null`  you are doing the wrong thing the `NULL` should be checked as the `=IIf(IsNothing(Fields!Customer_ID.Value),"", Fields!Customer_ID.Value)`. And  I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, Can you explain a little.

Comment: THANK YOU !!!!!! for your support.. i figured out !! I missed to use the same expression on the value box :P THANKS Expert !!

Comment: I am posting it as the answer, please accept as the answer so the question will be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For checking the null you are doing the wrong thing; the NULL should be checked as the `=IIf(IsNothing(Fields!Customer_ID.Value),"", Fields!Customer_ID.Value)`.

Comment: **for someone who may in need. To Clear a Filter in RDLC Filter. Filter by "" it will clear the filter..

just use the same expression you are trying on both Expression and Value boxes. **

Comment: Edit the answer with your comment I will pprove it